# Is it possible to call $('form').validationEngine('validate') with some custom options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I want to use the 'validate' method that is included jquery validation engine plugin, whilst also be able to pass in a few available options to ensure that the validation errors show in the correct way, such as the 'promptPosition' option.

Due to the nature of the framework that I am using which is Meteor.js, I cannot use the default submit functionality to submit a form, nor can I use Ajax straight off the bat. I would have to override default submit functionality, validate the form, then do the manipulations that I need to do to the backend, which is in javascript.

Is it possible to do something like this with this plugin?

```
$('form').validationEngine('validate', {promptPosition: 'topLeft' });
```

I know that you can just use: `$('form').validationEngine('validate')` but I do need some the plugin's custom options available similar when you use the 'attach' method.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I isn't possible to define options when calling `validate`. The only solution I can think of is to use something like this:

```
var myForm = $("form");  
myForm.validationEngine('attach', {promptPosition : "topLeft"});
// other js... 
// when you want to validate the form use:
myForm.validationEngine('validate');
```

You set the desired options when "attaching" the validation engine. You then trigger the validation manually. To prevent the validation getting triggered by the user just use a `button` instead of `input type="submit"`.

Here's a demo of what I'm trying to explain: http://jsfiddle.net/jxWp8/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the demo Joe. Although I found another way of doing, I'm marking this as correct for other users. :)

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible:

you can look at line 35 at this code for it specifically.

https://github.com/carlo379/bitstarter/blob/master/assets/js/toolspin.js

and you can view that form works in 
http://www.toolspin.com

it's how he implemented it for our school project